# How to use $_POST with URL Rewritting?

Tags: php, regex, apache

I've some problem with my code. I wanted to rewrite my URL's (changing %20 to hyphens).

So I wrote this in my .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+([^\s%20]+)((?:\s|%20)+.*)$ $1-$2$3 
 [N,DPI]
 RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]+)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$  $1-$2 [L,R=301,DPI]

 RewriteRule ^admin/ bootstrap.php?app=Backend [QSA,L]

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?app=Frontend [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It's working like expected :

My URLS are changed from : /news/The%20History%20of%20Cryptocurrency_3
                    to   : /news/The-History-of-Cryptocurrency_3

BUT for a reason i cannot understand : I lose my $_POST variable when a form is submitted...

==> When removing the rewrite rules, the code is working : I can submit a comment on a news and get the $_POST variables.
But if i put these rules, then $_POST show : array(0){}....

Here's the form :

```
<form method="post" action="/news/<?= $news['title'] ?>_<?= $news['id'] ?>" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: It sounds like the rewrite is sending a redirect, instead of just renaming it locally to the server. Redirects are always processed using `GET`.

Comment: How can i change my URL's to change %20 to '-' (hyphens) then ? Because i have forms on my page so $_POST variables

Comment: If I knew I would have posted an answer. [su] or [sf] might be better places to ask about Apache configuration.

Comment: Why not change the URL in the HTML that you're generating instead of generating a "bad" URL and rewriting it?

Comment: @GregSchmidt You mean with some str functions ? right in the views.php files ?

Comment: Exactly. `str_replace` would seem to be the thing.

Comment: thanks !! working nicely

Comment: Do yourself a favour and use a class to generate your slugs. Having str_replace stuff all across your code is just a recipe for disaster. Google "slug class php" and pick the one you like